# Linux Style Cronjob Command In Task Scheduler

Tags: php, cron, task

Hay everyone just wondering if any of you can help me.

I've just got this plugin that gets movie details from sites and imports the movies in my database. I've installed the plugin but it wants me to Set up a cronjob and add this command.

```
0 * * * *     cd C:/xampp/htdocs/plugins/moviefeed/ && php cron.php
```

But i do not have a linux server i've got a windows server using Xampp so is there any way i could put this command in Task Scheduler or could you point me in the right direction.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Here you can set up cron jobs.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please include more text in your response, this site demands high quality responses. Not a single line answer.